# Why am I not printing my array of strings correctly?

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf

I'm making a hangman game. They gave us the console output below (HANG_STATES).

```
char HANG_STATES[7][10 * 9] = 
{
    "             +         +----     +----     +----     +----     +----     +----     +----  ",
    "             |         |         |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O  ",
    "             |         |         |         |   +     | --+     | --+--   | --+--   | --+--",
    "             |         |         |         |   |     |   |     |   |     |   |     |   |  ",
    "             |         |         |         |         |         |         |  /      |  / \\ ",
    "             |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |      ",
    "/*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   /*****\\   "
};
```

How do I print only one string from among these 6 [edit: 0-6]? Every time I try to print them with

```
printf("%s", HANG_STATES[2]);
```

or `*(HANG_STATES + x)` format, it prints to the very end. I want it to stop at the next comma but it always goes from whatever index I start at to the very last character "\".

```
             +         +----     +----     +----     +----     +----     +----     +----               |         |         |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O     |   O               |  
       |         |         |   +     | --+     | --+--   | --+--   | --+--             |         |         |         |   |     |   |     |   |     |   |     |   |               |         |        
 |         |         |         |         |  /      |  / \              |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |      /*****\   /*****\   /*****\   /*****\   /*****\ 
  /*****\   /*****\   /*****\   /*****\
```

Interestingly when I made my own array of strings (I know they're 2-d arrays, but I call them array of strings), it worked just fine as expected. I don't see what the difference is.

```
char PEOPLE[3][10] = 
{
    "John", 
    "Jack",
    "James"
};
printf("%s", PEOPLE[1]);
Jack
```

Edit: I know that for the game I'll need to extract a section of each row to create columns, but I was simply trying to print each horizontal string for debugging purpose. It would go outside the range I expected it to, up to the very end of the final string"

Comment: Take your example and think about how you would print "JJJ" or "oaa" or "hcm" in columns.

Comment: "How do I print only one string from among these 6" is a bit confusing, the array contains 7 strings and 9 drawings.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I annotated my question with edits (specified). I want to actually print the horizontal even though I know it's not going to display the right pic for the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the strings in the array. The string isn't the vertical bits, but the horizontal bits.

E.g. `HANG_STATES[2]` is the string

```
"             |         |         |         |   +     | --+     | --+--   | --+--   | --+--"
```

You need to either figure out a way to print out the vertical bits, or to format each string differently.

My suggestion is to let each string be a *full* "image", including newlines, for the output. Perhaps something like this:

```
#define NUMBER_IMAGES  9

const char *HANG_STATES[NUMBER_IMAGES] = 
{
    // First image
    "          \n"
    "          \n"
    "          \n"
    "          \n"
    "          \n"
    "          \n"
    " /*****\\  \n",

    // Second image
    "   +      \n"
    "   |      \n"
    "   |      \n"
    "   |      \n"
    "   |      \n"
    "   |      \n"
    " /*****\\  \n",

    // And so on...
    // ...
};
```

---

After some clarification about the problem, it's simply that the array is *too small*. Your size of `10 * 9` is just *exactly* enough to fit the string itself, but not the string null terminator.

Therefore passing any of the strings to a string function will make the function run out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

The solution is to add one to the size: `10 * 9 + 1`.

<sub>[To nitpick, when using a larger size for the array the compiler doesn't technically add the string null terminator, it merely initializes the remaining uninitialized elements to zero. Which happens to be the same as the null terminator.]</sub>

Comment: Thanks this will actually be really helpful for later but I haven't gotten that far. I actually wanted to print the horizontal strings out just for testing purposes, except it didn't go as expected. If I print [2] it prints from 2-6, not strictly 2.

Comment: @gcr Ah, I see the problem now. And the problem is that your arrays are to small to fit the string null-terminator. Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, that fixed it. I just added +1 and then added \0 to end of string.

Comment: @gcr You don't need to add the terminator explicitly, the compiler will add a zero automatically.